# APIDemos 8 PersistenceState, where is the persistent text "saved?"

Tags: android, persistent

In the class PersistentState.java the prefs variable gets the saved/typed text from prior sessions here, on line 106 into restoredText.  Where does the getString method get the saved/typed text?

```
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
...

    SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(0); 
    String restoredText = prefs.getString("text", null);
```

Answer (score 0):

it will be a prefs file in the data directory

something like

```
/data/com.birthdroid/default.prefs
```